# Onclick button not working javascript. Calling a solve function from a .js file Sudoku

Tags: javascript

I need to create a sudoku solver, and I have all the code ready, but it seems to be an error in the solve button. Need some input on what to do. Is the error lying in the `isValid()` function or at the `solve()` function? I need to use backtracking to go through the grids of the puzzle and determine if a number is valid there.

here is `sudoku.js` (contains, a printboard, and a solve function):

```
//global variable
//accesible to all functions
var sol =
    [[0, 7, 0, 2, 3, 8, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 7, 4, 0, 8, 0, 9],
    [0, 6, 8, 1, 0, 9, 0, 0, 2],
    [0, 3, 5, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8],
    [6, 0, 7, 8, 0, 2, 5, 0, 1],
    [8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 7, 6, 0],
    [2, 0, 0, 6, 0, 3, 1, 9, 0],
    [7, 0, 9, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 9, 7, 4, 0, 8, 0]];
//this function prints the board
var printBoard = function () {
    for (let row = 0; row < sol.length; row += 1) {
        for (let col = 0; col < sol[row].length; col += 1) {
            let id = 'r' + (row + 1) + (col + 1);
            let elem = document.getElementById(id);
            elem.innerHTML = sol[row][col];
        }
    }
};

function isValid(sol, row, col, k) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        const m = 3 * Math.floor(row / 3) + Math.floor(i / 3);
        const n = 3 * Math.floor(col / 3) + i % 3;
        if (sol[row][i] == k || sol[i][col] == k || sol[m][n] == k) {
          return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

var solve = function() {
    for (let row = 0; row < 9; row++) {
        for (let col = 0; col < 9; col++) {
          if (sol[row][col] = 0) {
            for (let k = 1; k <= 9; k++) {
              if (isValid(sol, row, col, k)) {
                sol[row][col] = `${k}`;
              if (solve(sol)) {
               return true;
              } else {
               sol[row][col] = 0;
              }
             }
           }
           return false;
         }
       }
     }
     return true;
    }

printBoard();
```

and here is my `index.html` file (i call `solve()` with a button in this file):

```
<! DOCTYPE html >
<html>
  <head >
    <link rel ="stylesheet" href ="sudoku.css"/>
  </head >
  <body>
  <table >
    <tr >
    <td id='r11'> </td >
    <td id='r12'> </td >
    <td id='r13'> </td >
    <td id='r14'> </td >
    <td id='r15'> </td >
    <td id='r16'> </td >
    <td id='r17'> </td >
    <td id='r18'> </td >
    <td id='r19'> </td >
    </tr >
    <tr >
    <td id='r21' > </td >
    <td id='r22' > </td >
    <td id='r23' > </td >
    <td id='r24' > </td >
    <td id='r25' > </td >
    <td id='r26' > </td >
    <td id='r27' > </td >
    <td id='r28' > </td >
    <td id='r29' > </td >
    </tr >
    <tr >
    <td id='r31'> </td >
    <td id='r32'> </td >
    <td id='r33'> </td >
    <td id='r34'> </td >
    <td id='r35'> </td >
    <td id='r36'> </td >
    <td id='r37'> </td >
    <td id='r38'> </td >
    <td id='r39'> </td >
    </tr >
    <tr >
    <td id='r41'> </td >
    <td id='r42'> </td >
    <td id='r43'> </td >
    <td id='r44'> </td >
    <td id='r45'> </td >
    <td id='r46'> </td >
    <td id='r47'> </td >
    <td id='r48'> </td >
    <td id='r49'> </td >
    </tr >
    <tr >
    <td id='r51'> </td >
    <td id='r52'> </td >
    <td id='r53'> </td >
    <td id='r54'> </td >
    <td id='r55'> </td >
    <td id='r56'> </td >
    <td id='r57'> </td >
    <td id='r58'> </td >
    <td id='r59'> </td >
    </tr >
    <tr >
    <td id='r61'> </td >
    <td id='r62'> </td >
    <td id='r63'> </td >
    <td id='r64'> </td >
    <td id='r65'> </td >
    <td id='r66'> </td >
    <td id='r67'> </td >
    <td id='r68'> </td >
    <td id='r69'> </td >
    </tr >
    <tr >
    <td id='r71'> </td >
    <td id='r72'> </td >
    <td id='r73'> </td >
    <td id='r74'> </td >
    <td id='r75'> </td >
    <td id='r76'> </td >
    <td id='r77'> </td >
    <td id='r78'> </td >
    <td id='r79'> </td >
    </tr >
    <tr >
    <td id='r81'> </td >
    <td id='r82'> </td >
    <td id='r83'> </td >
    <td id='r84'> </td >
    <td id='r85'> </td >
    <td id='r86'> </td >
    <td id='r87'> </td >
    <td id='r88'> </td >
    <td id='r89'> </td >
    </tr >
    <tr >
    <td id='r91' > </td >
    <td id='r92' > </td >
    <td id='r93' > </td >
    <td id='r94' > </td >
    <td id='r95' > </td >
    <td id='r96' > </td >
    <td id='r97' > </td >
    <td id='r98' > </td >
    <td id='r99' > </td >
    </tr >
  </table >
  <button onclick="solve()">solve</button>
  </body >
  <script src ="sudoku.js"> </script>
  </html>
```

Comment: This code is super dense (not a bad thing).  If you're trying to track down your error, get comfy with your debugging tools.  Try throwing in a `debugger` statement, or using breakpoints.  That will help you narrow it down.

Comment: I found at least one error in your solve() function. An if statement `if (sol[row][col] = 0) {` is missing equation. It should be `sol[row][col] == 0`

Comment: I just ran a debug, and I am getting an error with the isValid function and when I call that function in the solve() function. It gives me an error: 'Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded'. Any way to apporach this?